# VIM refreshing buffer whenever I switch to it

Tags: vim, scp

I'm using VIM to edit files over SCP, so reading and writing files is a *very* slow process.

For some reason, whenever I switch to a buffer, VIM reads it from disk. The status bar says: ~@k.

I've disabled *all* autocommands in my .vimrc, and I have no autocommands for BufEnter anyway. Any idea what I might be missing?

Update: I found one culprit, a word-count macro which wasn't an auto-command. Now when I switch it's a tad faster but still slow. Status bar says ^Ww.

Update 2: I tried ZyX's answer below (Thanks!!). The results:

1) setting eventignore=all absolutely solves it; it's blazing fast. BUT
2) trying to debug it doesn't work for me.

I tried both `:debug buffer scp-buffer-name` and `:debug wincmd p` and got:

> Entering Debug mode. Type "cont" to continue.
>
> cmd: wincmd p
>
> line 1: for m in filter(copy(fuf#getModeNames()), 'fuf#{v:val}#requiresOnCommandPre()')`

And then no matter what I typed (s, n, "cont"), that single line would just repeat. It's obviously related to the Fuzzy Finder plugin, which I do use quite a lot and is a key reason for me to use VIM. Any ideas?

Thanks again for your help. Much appreciated, XyZ!

**ISSUE SOLVED:** It was indeed Fuzzy Finder. It has a MRU-File mode which documentation notes may cause a performance issue when switching buffers. I disabled this mode and now VIM is fast again! Thanks!

Comment: Can't edit my question for some reason. I found one culprit, a word-count macro which wasn't an auto-command. Now when I switch it's a tad faster but still slow. Status bar says ^Ww.

Comment: Not sure you still have a question but if you want to know the default behaviour of `^Ww` you can check `:help CTRL-W_w`. It is used basically to move from one window to another.

Comment: Maybe the `'autoread'` setting was on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, test this behavior with `set eventignore=all`. If the problem gets fixed, try to switch to scp buffer using (be sure you have unset eventignore) `debug buffer scp-buffer-name` or `debug wincmd p` (depending on when you see the problem), it will open debug mode and you will be able to see all autocommands it is executing (use `s[tep]` or `n[ext]` to move to next command, see `:h >next` and `:h >step` for more details).